# Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145) no deployment target iOS 11.1 and 11.2

Tags: xcode, configure

I update my xcode to 9.3(9E145) through App Store. I use the CoreML which demand iOS 11.2, but there is no iOS 11.1 and 11.2 in Deployment Target list(only iOS 11.0 and 11.3). but others xcode is ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your target's Deployment Target popup menu doesn't list your preferred deployment target, you can manually type it into the box:
[image: Manually Set Deployment Target]
Here, I've set it to 7.0 (which is impractical for anything shipping today).  You can certainly type in "11.2" there.

Comment: thx. Yes, I have tried this way, but in fact, it's useless. I mean, this way can't actually use the real 11.2, because Core ML model is error also.

Comment: I just verified it was working on my Xcode 9.3 sample project (with CoreML included as a linked framework). Could you edit your question to show a screenshot (or a link to a screenshot) of those errors?